# Touchscreen on KDE and Ubuntu?

Tags: linux, ubuntu, kde, touchscreen

I just bought a Lenovo Yoga 2 Pro... I liked the activity of the touchscreen on Windows, and it makes sense as it does on my smart phone. However, I'm not a regular windows user, so I installed Kubuntu 14.04, and everything looks fine, except that the activity of the touchscreen is so silly that it's useless.

Why? Because all the touchscreen does is a single mouse with left click. For example, if I touch the screen for a relatively long time, I don't get the effect of a right click.

How do I configure the touchscreen properly to get the activity expected on Ubuntu and KDE?

Thanks for any efforts.

Answer (score 0):

You could try [Touchégg](https://code.google.com/p/touchegg/).

It's not perfect, as it translates touchscreen gestures into mouse clicks, so you could get long press to right click, for example, but drag to scroll and pinch to zoom wouldn't work very well.